# docker-compose seems to ignore .env-variables on mariadb

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm having problems with `docker-compose` for a while now and can't figure out what's going on there. Given is the following scenario - which worked before but stopped working on a new project and now on every new stack I build up:

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57  
$ docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.2.2

OS: Pop!_OS 21.10 (NVIDIA)
```

Filestructure:

```
/myfolder
+ app-src (containing my laravel-project)
+ database-dumps (for database-dumps - containing a .gitkeep-file)
+ database_persist (for persistent data - containing a .gitkeep-file)
- .env
- .gitignore
- buildcontrainer.sh (custom script)
- container-start.sh (custom script)
- docker-compose.yml
- migrate-database.sh (custom script)
- README.md
```

This is the shortened `docker-compose.yml-file` (shortened, because it only affects the database... nginx and the php-container are working fine):

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    image: mariadb:10.6.1
    ports:
      - "${DB_EXPOSE_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./database_persist:/var/lib/mysqldata"
```

And the .env-File:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=MyProject

DB_DATABASE="myprojectdb"
DB_USER="myproject"
DB_PASSWORD="12345"
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD="12345"
DB_EXPOSE_PORT=9036

WEB_EXPOSE_PORT_HTTP=9080
WEB_EXPOSE_PORT_HTTPS=9043
```

Now to my problem - whenever I try to set up an environment like given in the scenario and I run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` afterwards I get the following output:

```
Creating network "myproject_default" with the default driver
Creating myproject_database_1 ... done
Attaching to myproject_database_1
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.1+maria~focal started.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.1+maria~focal started.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:53 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
database_1  | 
database_1  | 
database_1  | PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
database_1  | To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
database_1  | 
database_1  | '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'
database_1  | '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h  password 'new-password'
database_1  | 
database_1  | Alternatively you can run:
database_1  | '/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'
database_1  | 
database_1  | which will also give you the option of removing the test
database_1  | databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
database_1  | strongly recommended for production servers.
database_1  | 
database_1  | See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb or the
database_1  | MySQL manual for more instructions.
database_1  | 
database_1  | Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira
database_1  | 
database_1  | The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
database_1  | You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:
database_1  | https://dev.mysql.com
database_1  | Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
database_1  | https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal) starting as process 110 ...
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.1 started; log sequence number 42616; transaction id 18
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@66d18f02ea8a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@66d18f02ea8a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211225 15:30:57
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:57 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
database_1  | Version: '10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:30:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@66d18f02ea8a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database myprojectdb
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user myproject
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user myproject access to schema myprojectdb
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] mysqld (initiated by: root[root] @ localhost []): Normal shutdown
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 211225 15:31:01
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 42628; transaction id 19
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:01 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB init process done. Ready for start up.
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.1 started; log sequence number 42628; transaction id 18
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@66d18f02ea8a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211225 15:31:02
database_1  | 2021-12-25 15:31:02 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
database_1  | Version: '10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

It looks to me as if the `.env-parameters` are not given to the database-container anymore. All attempts recreating the database-container with `docker-compose build`, or removing all images via `docker image prune` and `docker-compose pull` have been in vain. I have updated my OS from 21.04 to 21.10 two days ago, but I don't think it causes the issue (just stated it here if it does). Does someone has an idea on how to fix this? Setting the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` directly in `the docker-compose.yml` did not help either. The permission on database_persist are set via `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER database_persist/` so that should not be an issue as well.

Thanks (and merry Christmas :) )

Edit: I tried reinstalling docker and updating docker-compose to version 2.2.2 (edited accordingly), but it had no effect. One of the commentors asked if I can connect to the container. Yes, I can, but not as root.

Comment: Can you connect afterwards with the user/password or not?

Comment: Yes I can, but not as root. See my edit.

Comment: If you can use that user and pw, it means the env file has been read and used, otherwise it would work at all. Are you sure you use the correct name for the root password variable?

Comment: Yes - I am sure I used the right one. Like I said - I copied it from an existing project and just adjusted the variables. Plus - it worked before and doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

The `.env` file can be parsed as a part of the `docker-compose.yaml`. Though I personally never used this the way you do, as you can also pass a file directly into the container. With the `env_file` key

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    env_file: .env
    image: mariadb:10.6.1
    ports:
      - "${DB_EXPOSE_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./database_persist:/var/lib/mysqldata"
```

Obviously, you then also need to change the variable names in your .env file. And I personally would rename it to a more clear name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - Problem is that docker-compose should automaticly parse a .env-file named only ".env" according to documentation. Plus - even if I put the vars directly in the yaml, they are not processed.

Comment: Yes, it should be. Though, I used it only as displayed in the documentation. in the Image or for a port number. The ` even if I put the vars directly in the yam` is a good hint, overlooked that in your question, Sorry. It is the Christmas wine is to blame, ;) Did you try removing the `database_persist ` directory combined with the fixed written content?

Comment: Hahaha - no worries... :)
Edit: It's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - for some weird reason the output stays the same, but when I try to login the dbroot and the dbuser actually use their passwords specified in the env-files. Plus using anything else will result in a "access denied". So I don't know if the update fixed the issue or if the logoutput just scared me and this is actually the expected behaviour. I will update this if I get any new insights.

Comment: didnt you say it doesnt work with the root pwd?

Comment: Yes - but it did after the reinstall + update.

Comment: I suspect it was working all the time. Thats also why I asked if is its working, initially. I think that kind of message always shows. Its also unlikely that one variable is passed but another not. Potentially, you have changed the password to something other than what was already saved in the volume. A restart will not change the password stored there. Its only set once for the lifetime of that volume. Rebuild does nothing in that case, since its  a *vanilla* image. There is nothing to build.